# Jackson: How to De-Serialize a JSON with Custom Quote Char?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson allows the configuration of a custom quote char for serialization.

I have a simple class, I want to (de)serialize:

```
public class MyInfo {

    private String info;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Serialization works fine with a custom char (`X` instead of `"`):

```
        MyInfo info = new MyInfo("test string");
        
        JsonFactoryBuilder jfb = new JsonFactoryBuilder();
        JsonFactory jf = jfb.quoteChar('X').build();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(jf);
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(info);
        System.out.println(s);
```

results in: `{XinfoX:Xtest stringX}` - as expected.

When I try to serialize that string, again (`mapper` is the same as above):

```
info = mapper.readValue(s, MyInfo.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('X' (code 88)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{XinfoX:Xtest stringX}"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2337)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:710)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1814)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:713)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3516)
```

How do I enable the custom quote char for de-serialization?

Comment: My read of the code is jackson will only parse standard quoting with the exception that there are two features you can enable to parse unquoted field names (`ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES`) and single-quoted strings (`ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES` ). Why do you want to replace quotes?

Comment: @roby I have a service that I need to exchange data with. It uses a non-standard quote character. I'm trying to get that changed, but this might take a wile so I have to work around that limitation for now.